# Multiple index.html files inside folder structure

Tags: html, apache, web

I just came up with an idea. Instead of using an `.htaccess` file to remove `.html` from the URL, why not just use a simple folder structure and in each folder add an `index.html`?

For instance:

- `example.com/index.html` → *Home*
- `example.com/about/index.html` → *About*

Now simply use a hyperlink on the homepage to the about folder, since typically `index.html` files are opened automatically.

The upside of this kind of navigation, is that it would be easily possible to create sub pages with no crazy database / `.htaccess` setup.

Now my question is: is there any reason not to create a webpage like that and is it legitimate to use multiple `index.html` files?

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `index.html` route, there would be three URL's that can access the same page. For example for an about page:

- `www.yourwebsite.com/about`
- `www.yourwebsite.com/about/`
- `www.yourwebsite.com/about/index.html`

Using the `.htaccess` file would likely give you more benefit from an SEO perspective. You can tell the search engine which one to use, by using 301 redirects. See more about how Google does this here:

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Of course you could set up your website using folders and index.html's, and still 
use the `.htaccess` file to take care of the SEO. But, depending on your sites size and structure, this might be more work.

Answer (score 0):

The only downsides would be having to create a folder in addition to a file whenever you want to create a new page, and having to take more time to navigate into a folder in order to edit a page.

As long as you are using [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), or a similar server software, multiple index files will function normally and be served from each folder.